# How can I encrypt SQL Server databse that can't use by the others?

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption

I am a server manager and there are many databases in our servers and I worry about illegal access to databases.

I need to encrypt the databases that nobody can't use them, even they have a backup from db.

I'm thinking about an encryption that the database only accessible with user/password permission and if someone has access to the servers, can't use the databases.

How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have an answer for your exact question, but a couple of options to consider.

The first one is using Transparent Data Encryption (TDE), but this option one only addresses somebody the scenario of somebody stealing a backup of the DB, it doesn’t help you on a database that is online.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

The second feature to consider is Always Encrypted (AE), this option doesn’t protect the DB as a whole, but it is an option to separate the database from the keys protecting the sensitive data in such a way that only the applications with access to the root key (column master key) can access the data in plaintext. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx

As I said, neither one covers your needs completely, but using both of them in tandem may be good enough for your scenario.